# Is this question still unclear?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

The question below received a comment stating that it's unclear. Then OP updated the question and it became totally clear (at least to me), however it was put on hold 2 days after the edit.

[Options for getting from Kayseri (Turkey) to Goreme](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/123088/options-for-getting-from-kayseri-turkey-to-goreme)

I think this question should be reopened.

Comment: Question reopened. Next time just ping the mods in chat and we'll help out.